# Even product on 5 dice rolls

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A fair die (d6) is thrown five times. What is the probability that the product of the five scores is even?

I have tried the following approaches.
The first seems unnecessarily complex and also wrong:

> Consider placeholder odd numbers $O_1, O_2, O_3$. We want the complement of the multiset
> "all possible multisets containing odd numbers only". To find this multiset divide amongst
> $O_1, O_2, O_3$ number of times each occurs such that the number of occurrences adds up to 5. There are $ ^{5+3-1}C_5$ such divisions.
> The tuples are (these aren't ordered) $(0,0,5), (0,1,4), (0,2,3), (1,1,3), (1,2,2)$.
>
> So the solution is $1-6^{-5} \displaystyle \left(\frac{ ^3 C_1}{3!} + \frac{ ^3 C_2}{2!2!} + \frac{ ^3 C_2 ^2 C_1}{3!2!} + \frac{ ^3 C_2 ^2 C_1}{4!}+ \frac{^3 C_1}{5!}\right)$.

The other seems too simplistic and also wrong.

> $p = \Pr (even) = \frac1{2}$. Using binomial probability the solution is $1-\, ^5\!C_0 \, 2^{-5} = \frac{31}{32}$.

What is the simplest possible way to do this question that provides a correct answer?

Comment: Your second solution is correct and is the standard approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The product will not be even only if you get $1$ or $3$ or $5$ **every time** you roll the die.

These are $3$ out of $6$ options, so the probability for that after $n$ attempts is $(\dfrac{3}{6})^n$.

So the probability that the product will not be even after $5$ attempts is $(\dfrac{3}{6})^5$.

And therefore, the probability that the product will be even is  $1-(\dfrac{3}{6})^5$.

Comment: The product is even unless each of the rolls is odd.  Thus, the probability that the product is not even is $$\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^5 = \frac{1}{32}$$

Comment: @N.F.Taussig: Where does that come in contrast with anything I said in the answer???

Comment: @barakmanos It was just a little more succinct than your answer, which is correct.